# How to check the Queue is empty or how many items are in it of Queued background service in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, ihostedservice

I want to implement the QueueBackground service in asp.net core.

1. I need to check the queue is empty or not?
2. How to count the items which are in Queue?

Comment: this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/queue-service or?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8. If you want to perform background processing, maybe you can use HangFire

Comment: @sommmen .. yes this one